# How to enable Pointer Location by code?

Tags: android

Does any body know how to enable pointer location options on by java code?
 `Settings > Developer Options > Pointer Location`
and toggle that on

Comment: I used Tasker to toggle this... sure would like a simple intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

then import this to your class:

```
import android.provider.Settings;
```

and write settings like this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                "show_touches", 1);

Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                "pointer_location", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, not all devices may have the Developer Options unlocked (as they are hidden by default).

Now, it is not possible to stealthily enable Pointer Location input programmatically, but you can show the user the respective Setting screen by including:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

where they can enable/disable it.